# Present a UIScrollView when opening an App for the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have an iPad App that I want to be compatible from iOS 5.0 to 6.0. My main view contains a scroll view z-indexed on the front, which is initially set to hidden. I also have a toolbar containing a button that cycle the scroll view hidden or not.

I would like to add a feature to present the scroll view as initially visible when the user opens the App for the first time to make the help visible by default to new users.

My code to cycle between visible and hidden is the following:

```
- (void)showHelpView:(id)sender {
BOOL hidden = [blackTranslucent isHidden];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollViewOutlet];
if (hidden) {
[scrollViewOutlet setHidden:FALSE animationStyle:KGAnimationFade duration:0.7];
[blackTranslucent setHidden:FALSE animationStyle:KGAnimationFade duration:0.5];
}
else {
[scrollViewOutlet setHidden:TRUE animationStyle:KGAnimationFade duration:0.5];
[blackTranslucent setHidden:TRUE animationStyle:KGAnimationFade duration:0.7];
}
}
```

where the sender is my toolbar button, blackTranslucent is a view on top of the main view and scrollViewOutlet is my scroll view IBOutlet.

Comment: Did you have an actual question/problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property "isNewUser" on `NSUserDefaults` in the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method which will only be written once by checking if the key exists.

In your main view in the `viewDidLoad` check this property if true make the view visible and update the key to false. if not just continue regularly.

[Further information on NSUserDefaults](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/NSUserDefaults.html)

Hope that helps